# In SqlDataAdapter query isn't working after passing a concatenated string as a query string, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a desktop app using C# and SQL Server 2014. In my `SqlDataAdapter`, the SQL query isn't working after passing a concatenated string as a variable.
If I write queries as direct string - it worked fine. But manually entering 100+ tags is an idiocy. I couldn't figure it out yet - what's wrong with my code?

```
// block 17. created for splitting unique word from whole user tag text and searching with this tags in database; it returns a unique word!

String Input = search.Text;
Input = Input + " ";

String[] Word_Box = new String[1000];
String Word = "";
int T = 0, Len;
Len = Input.Length;
bool  flag = false;

for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
{
    if (Input[i] != ' ')
    {
        Word = Word + Input[i];
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (Input[i] == ' ' && flag == true)
    {
        Word_Box[T++] = Word;
        Word = "";
        flag = false;
    }
}
// block end

// block 18. start for adjusting SQL query string for searching purpose :)
String Query_String;
Query_String = "select * from Tbl_Test3 where";
int WordCount = T - 2;

for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    Query_String = Query_String + " Tags like '%\"+ \""+ Word_Box[i] +"\" + \"%' ";
    if (i <= WordCount)
    {
        Query_String += "OR ";
    }
}
// block end

con.Open();

//Query_String = "select * from Tbl_FinalTest3 where Tags like '%"+ "Codeforces" + "%' OR  Tags like '%"+ "Topcoder" + "%' ";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(Query_String, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

No error is shown & after executing, the datagridview doesn't show any data, where same output of direct string is displayed perfectly.

I have no doubt with that line, then what's wrong?

```
Query_String = Query_String + " Tags like '%\"+ \""+ Word_Box[i] +"\" + \"%' ";
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `Query_String` in the debugger? Does it look correct there?

Comment: yes its worked fine

Comment: i lastly outputted whole string in a textbox, then copy that just adding " " start and end like-

Query_String = "select * from Tbl_Test3 where Tags like '%"+ "Codeforces" + "%' OR  Tags like '%"+ "Topcoder" + "%' ";

Comment: Another excellent reason to use parameters.

Comment: then whats the solution i have?

Comment: If you take the last outputted string you've shown and actually run that query as is, do you get any results?

Comment: yeah... all data are visible..

Comment: The query string formed is not with respect to database query. I would suggest you to frame it like `Query_String = Query_String + $" Tags like '%{Word_Box[i]}%' ";`

Comment: @VenkataramanR Its Working :)

Comment: Glad to note that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Venkataraman R's Comment- I Solved this problem.
didn't know that before about this. It will be useful many of us.
Finally, its working nicely with-

```
Query_String = Query_String + $" Tags like '%{Word_Box[i]}%' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

Just tested your query structure and it appears that the '+' signs are confusing things. When you end up with '%"+ "Codeforces" + "%' for example, it's actually searching for '%+Codeforces+%' instead of '%Codeforces%'. Try using [SQL CONCAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp) like this:

```
Query_String = Query_String + " Tags like CONCAT('%', '" + Word_Box[i] + "','%')";
```

Comment: I tried it before, again executing now by copying from as yours.. 
same thing happening.. no change at all :(

Comment: @AdaLovelace - have you verified your connection is correct for the SqlAdapter?

Comment: if not, then why its OK on direct string? I think- its ok.. main problem appear when i pass it as a variable.. doesn't showing any error, and no output . but datagridview remain blank. its a point.

Comment: @AdaLovelace It does sound like it's ok if it works with a direct string. I've edited my answer as I just noticed I forgot to add in some additional double quotes. The string would just show the actual words Word_Box[i] otherwise.

Comment: I made the same mistake, as a result- the error showed. & You wrote the same mistake that I made before, and in the meantime I resolved it by Venkataraman's approach. Later, I was able to solve it with 'CONCAT' also.
BTW, Thanks for extending a helping hand in SO.